# Set Harmony flags in the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, ecmascript-6

I'm playing with ES6 by running it on **io.js** with different flags like:

```
iojs --harmony_arrow_functions arrow.es6
iojs --harmony_modules --harmony_destructuring importer.es6
```

But it is very boring to constantly write this flags manually and
I always confuse what flags are necessary for a particular file. Can I set the flags in the files like:

```
process.env['--harmony_modules'];
process.env['--harmony_destructuring']; or
process.env['flags'] = ['--harmony_modules', '--harmony_destructuring'];
```

Or run **io.js** with **./config** file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just experimenting with ES6, try the [babel.js REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/). Also check their [setup page](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/) which gives instructions on how to use babel to transpile your code on the fly (for lots of different tools/use-cases).

If you don't want to use a transpiler like babel.js, then you could just create an alias or script that executes io.js with all the harmony flags enabled and then use that to start all your scripts. For example, as an alias:

```
alias iojs-es6='iojs --harmony_arrow_functions --etc...'
```

Note that with io.js (V8 4.1+) all [stable ES6 features are enabled by default](https://iojs.org/en/es6.html). So you only need to provide the flag for anything else:

- `staging` - enabled using `--es_staging` - currently just `Symbol.toStringTag`
- `in progress` - currently
  `:
  --harmony_modules
  --harmony_arrays
  --harmony_array_includes
  --harmony_regexps
  --harmony_arrow_functions
  --harmony_proxies
  --harmony_sloppy
  --harmony_unicode`

Answer (score 1):

io.js merged with Node: https://iojs.org

You said it was annoying to pass flags every time.
You can add a script to your package.json like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --es_staging --harmony_destructuring server.js"
  }
```

Then `npm run start` or `npm start` for short will run your script.

Many ES2015/ES6 features are now enabled in Node out-of-the-box:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/

You can run node with stable ES2015 features that aren't automatically enabled like this:
`node --es_staging server.js`

You can run this command in Bash to see all of the harmony flags:
`node --v8-options | grep harmony`

For example, to get ES2015 features plus destructuring (not currently stable as of Node 5.3):

`node --es_staging --harmony_destructuring server.js`

For keeping Node up-to-date, nvm is great: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm